# A tricky integral (flux of a point charge through a disk)

Tags: calculus, integration, elliptic-integrals, solid-angle

**The integrals:**
$$
\oint \frac{r\,dr\,d\phi}{\left(L^2+r^2+h^2+2Lr\cos\phi\right)^{3/2}}\\
\oint \frac{dx\,dy}{\left((L+x)^2+y^2+h^2\right)^{3/2}}
$$

[image]If we have a point charge at the origin and we want to find the flux through a disk of radius $R$ which is located at $(x,0,z)$ and lies parallel to the $x-y$ plane we will have to do a tricky integral. We can write down the exact $E.dA$ or we can try and find the solid angle (turns out it is like finding the flux through an ellipse at $(0,0,z)$).

What I'm looking for is the answer to that integral or the solid angle. I thought the integral wasn't doable. But recently I came across a physical way of finding it using greens reciprocity theorem. If you can find it from that, then the integral should be doable as well!

To be clear: this is entirely a math problem. We have an inverse square vector field. We want its flux through a disk.
for example take the (x=0) situation.we can simply use gauss law and just find the solid angle to obtain the flux.ot write out the integral by using r and theta as variables.but even at this situation doing it with dxdy integral is tough.

Comment: I dont have access to LaTeX to write down the integral but its simple.the hard part is evaluating it.c'mon people please help me in this!!

Comment: 1) the whiff of desperation will not help you much here, 2) you are getting no response because your description of the problem is poor,  I suggest you link to a picture of the geometry and the equation.

Comment: you are right Mr.Gordon but I couldnt write the integral itself in LaTeX so I had to go with this crappy description.I added a picture.hope it helps.and to be clear:I know how to write the integral.trick is how to do this? I get an elliptic in cartesian.sadly!

Comment: @iman: for future reference, use MathJax (see explanation here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ) in order to typeset mathematics as I did.

Answer (score 5):

The solid angle can be expressed in terms of complete elliptic integrals of first and third kind.
I believe this is first derived by F. Paxton in 1959.

> THE REVIEW OF SCIENTIFIC INSTRUMENTS. VOLUME 30, NUMBER 4 APRIL, 1959.
>   Solid Angle Calculation for a Circular Disk. F. PAXTON

A copy of the article can be found 
[here](http://www.umich.edu/~ners312/Course%20Library/SolidAngleOfADiskOffAxis.pdf).

*Below is my attempt to derive the same result in an alternate manner.

The integral is indeed trickier than I thought.*

To avoid confusion with the usage of $x,y,z$ as coordinates, let us change the problem and assume the circular disk $C$ we are dealing with lies in the plane $z = b$, centered at $(a,0,b)$ with radius $s$. We will assume $a, b > 0$ and $a \ne s$.

In terms of ordinary spherical polar coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$, points on the plane $z = b$ can be parametrized as:

$$(x,y,z) = (b\tan\theta \cos\phi,\,b\tan\theta\sin\phi,\, b)$$
Let $\rho = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = b\tan\theta$, the "element" for integrating the solid angle is given by:

$$d\Omega 
= \sin\theta d\theta \wedge d\phi 
=\frac{\tan\theta d\tan\theta}{\sqrt{1 + \tan\theta^2}^3} \wedge d\phi
= \frac{b \rho d\rho \wedge d\phi}{\sqrt{\rho^2+b^2}^3} 
= \frac{b\;dx \wedge dy}{\sqrt{\rho^2+b^2}^3}
$$
Introduce complex coorindates $\eta = x + iy$ and $\bar{\eta} = x - iy$, the solid angle
extended by $C$ can be rewritten as:

$$\begin{align}
\Omega_{C} 
= & \int_{C} d\Omega 
= \frac{b}{2i}\int_{C} \frac{d\bar{\eta} \wedge d\eta}{\sqrt{\eta\bar{\eta}+b^2}^3}
=\color{blue}{^{[1]}} \frac{b}{i} \int_C d\left(\frac{1}{\eta}\left( \frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\eta\bar{\eta}+b^2}}\right)\right) \wedge d\eta\\
= & \frac{b}{i} \int_{\partial C} \left(\frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\eta\bar{\eta} + b^2}}\right) \frac{d\eta}{\eta}
= 2\pi \delta_{C} + ib \int_{\partial C} \frac{d\eta}{\eta \sqrt{\eta\bar{\eta} + b^2}}
\end{align}$$
where $\delta_{C} = 1 \text{ or } 0$ depends on whether $s > a$ or $< a$. In other words, whether $\partial C$ contains $0$ or not.

On $\partial C$, we can parametrize $\eta$ as $s e^{it} + a$ and $\bar{\eta}$ as $s e^{-it} + a$. Substitute this into above expression, we obtain:

$$\begin{align}
&\Omega_C - 2\pi \delta_{C}\\
= &ib \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{ dt }{\sqrt{ s^2 + a^2 + b^2 + 2sa\cos t}}\frac{ is e^{it}}{s e^{it} + a }\\
= & -b
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{ dt }{\sqrt{ s^2 + a^2 + b^2 + 2sa\cos t}}
\left( \frac{s e^{it}}{s e^{it} + a } + \frac{s e^{-it}}{s e^{-it} + a } \right)\\
= & -b
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{ dt }{\sqrt{ s^2 + a^2 + b^2 + 2sa\cos t}}
\frac{2s(s + a\cos t)}{s^2 + a^2 + 2sa\cos t}\\
= & -b
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{ dt }{\sqrt{ s^2 + a^2 + b^2 + 2sa\cos t}}
\left( 1 + \frac{s^2 - a^2}{s^2 + a^2 + 2sa\cos t} \right)\\
= & -2b
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{ dt }{\sqrt{ s^2 + a^2 + b^2 + 2sa\cos(2t)}}
\left( 1 + \frac{s^2 - a^2}{s^2 + a^2 + 2sa\cos(2t)} \right)\\
= & -2b
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{ dt }{\sqrt{ (s+a)^2 + b^2 - 4sa\sin^2(t)}}
\left( 1 + \frac{s^2 - a^2}{(s+a)^2 - 4sa\sin^2(t)} \right)
\end{align}$$
The last integral can be expressed in terms of the 
[complete elliptic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)
of first and third kind:
$$
K(k) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^{2}t}}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\Pi(n,k) = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{dt}{(1-n\sin^{2}t)\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^{2}t}}
$$

The final results are:
$$\Omega_{C} = 2\pi\delta_C -\frac{2b}{\sqrt{(s+a)^2+b^2}} 
\left(\;K(k) + \left(\frac{s-a}{s+a}\right) \Pi(n,k)\;\right)
$$
where $\displaystyle \;\;k = \sqrt{\frac{4sa}{(s+a)^2+b^2}}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
n = \frac{4sa}{(s+a)^2}
$.

***Notes***

$\color{blue}{[1]}$ When $C$ contains $(0,0,b)$, we need the $\frac{1}{b}$ term. It regularize the 1-form at $\eta = 0$ and make Stroke's theorem continue to work.

Comment: thank you sir!It was so nice of you to work it out.and a great refrence also.but im a bit uneasy about the wedge thing..it is cross product right?also using complex coordinates..is it just a convention to make things simpler ?

Comment: @iman the wedge is the wedge product. The standard tool for dealing with differential forms. I use complex coordinates to make the conversion from surface to line integral easier. Sometimes it will be easier to guess what the line integral looks like when complex coordinates are used. One should be able to derive same result using pure vector analysis and [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem).